# Angular 6 Update - rxjs-5-to-6-migrate command not found

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

In the upgrade process from [update.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/):

> Remove deprecated RxJS 6 features using rxjs-tslint auto update rules.
>
> For most applications this will mean running the following two commands:
>
> ```
> npm install -g rxjs-tslint
> rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
> ```

But when I follow these steps and run `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json` I'm getting the error:

```
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate: command not found
```

Is there any reason why this command isn't working?

Comment: try running `node node_modules/.bin/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate`.

Comment: @martin Geting an error still: `Error: Cannot find module...`

Comment: Yeah that was installed _only_ globally, so it won't be in the project's `node_modules/`.

Comment: Even when I install rxjs-tslint with --save-dev, I'm still getting the error from the OP

Answer (score 55):

I did get it working and my steps are the following:

1. Install `rxjs-tslint` locally - `cd YOUR_PROJECT_DIR && npm i rxjs-tslint`.
2. Then run from your project root `node_modules/.bin/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p PATH_TO_YOUR_TSCONFIG.json`.
3. If you get an error saying something like `rxjs-tslint/node_modules/.bin/tslint: not found`, then do `cd node_modules/rxjs-tslint && npm install` and repeat the step 2.

Comment: Thanks! How did you figure this out? (`cd node_modules/rxjs-tslint && npm install`) ?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, `rxjs-tslint` was just complaining about some missing dependency and I thought there could be a problem installing `peerDependencies`, so I decided to try to run the `npm install` manually from the package directory.

Comment: really clever. Thanks for sharing it with the world

Comment: You made my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am using a Windows 7 machine, for me, Step 2 didn't work. I have to modify the command to  node_modules/.bin/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.cmd -p PATH_TO_YOUR_TSCONFIG.json.

Comment: thanks man , you saved my day  (after i wasted day solving myself)
i also followed Prakash update and made it like 
node_modules/.bin/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.cmd -p ./src/tsconfig.app.json  --allow-dirty

Answer (score 11):

When I got this, I had to follow the following steps. They took me a while to figure out, so I figure I should share them here:

1. run `npm install rxjs-tslint`
2. run `cd node_modules/rxjs-tslint`
3. run `npm install`
4. `cd` back out of your `node_modules` directory, back to your project home
5. run `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p ./tsconfig.json`

On step #5 you make need to change the path to point to your `tsconfig.json` file. But that is where mine was. It finally worked!

Hope it works for you like it worked for me.

Comment: 1. npm install rxjs-tslist > npm install rxjs-tslint

Comment: Also this didn't work for me, still the same error message. Running node_modules/.bin/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p <tsconfig.json path> worked

Answer (score 3):

Follow the instruction to install the dependency globally then try using the full path to the file rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.

For example:
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rxjs-tslint/bin/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json`

If you don't know where the dependencies are stored on your computer you can run `npm root -g`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my command:

```
npx rxjs-tslint -p app/tsconfig.app.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Having this issues when executing the command

> npx rxjs-tslint -p src/tsconfig.app.json

Running the automatic migrations. Please, be patient and wait until the execution completes.

*Invalid option for project: src/tsconfig.app.json
Error while running the migration: ,,Invalid option for project: src/tsconfig.app.json*