# Rxjs 5 to 6 migration not working during angular 6 upgrade

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular6

I'm upgrading my app to angular 6 and following [this](https://update.angular.io/) guide. But the upgrade process is NOT as smooth as they claim it to be.

I'm currently struggling trying to migrate rxjs 5 to 6 using the following command.

```
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

**What I did:**

First I ran: `npm install -g rxjs-tslint` which gave me the output below:

[image]

```
npm WARN tslint@5.9.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@2.29.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >= 3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN rxjs-tslint@0.1.5 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So I then manually installed these missing peer dependencies.

The I ran: `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json` and I got the output below:

[image]

```
Running the automatic migrations. Please, be patient and wait until the execution completes.
child_process.js:644
throw err;
^

Error: Command failed: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rxjs-tslint/node_modules/.bin/tslint" -c "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rxjs-tslint/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.json" -p "src/tsconfig.app.json" --fix
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
at Object.execSync (child_process.js:641:13)
at migrate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rxjs-tslint/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.js:18:34)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rxjs-tslint/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.js:25:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
```

I can't seem to fix it, I've tried googling the issue and still no luck.

Comment: Please post your textual errors as text.

Comment: Did you even read the output of the first error message?

Comment: @crooksey yeah I did and I installed the peer dependencies.

Comment: And if you try and re-install rxjs-tslint, do you get any warnings?

Comment: @trichetriche done.

Comment: @crooksey it keeps giving the same error. I've uninstalled and installed them multiple times.

Comment: I think this would solve your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330546/angular-6-update-rxjs-5-to-6-migrate-command-not-found)

Comment: @vsvk thanks you but I tried that and it didn’t work :(

Answer (score 1):

Try these 2 :  First update rxjs to version 5.5 and fix issues if any, then try to migrate from 5 to 6 or Delete node_modules folder and install again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm running version 6.2.2 for rxjs. Should I downgrade to 5.5?

Comment: You can downgrade and check if it works. Have you tried re install of node modules?